# Why does my socket.io app disconnect immediately when run on Raspberry pi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to build a node.js application on a Raspberry Pi which can communicate with a remote socket.io server.

The socket.io server quite simply writes to the console when a new connection is established and when an existing connection is closed.

The socket.io client works as expected when run in a browser.

However, when I run the client code from a Raspberry Pi it connects and immediately terminates. This does not allow me to perform any function such as emitting or receiving.

The on connect event is never fired.

```
var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io-client');
var serverUrl = 'http://remoteserver.com';

console.log('Connecting to ' + serverUrl);
var socket = io.connect(serverUrl);

socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connection established!');
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Disconnected from server');
    });

});
```

The code above will output:

```
Connecting to: http://remoteserver.com
```

On the server side, the output will show a new connection and eventually a timeout close.

Why is the client on connect event not firing? How can I persist this connection so that I can eventually send inputs to the server?

Comment: because you are closing the connection instantly.

Comment: You should add some error handling: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#event-connect_error Does the server implement some sort of authentication (based on session cookies or something)?

Comment: Make sure you're not making the connection behind a proxy or aggressive application firewall as this can result in the issue you're describing. The initial connection will succeed, but the rest of the socket traffic will never make it back and your client will eventually timeout and close.

Comment: On the node side try "connection" event instead of "connect"

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line:

```
socket.close();
```

from your code.  You are closing the socket immediately.  Remember that all the event handlers are asynchronous.  They are non-blocking and will be called some time in the future.  Meanwhile, the rest of your code runs to completion and thus your `socket.close()` is executed before your client has any chance to get any events (other than the disconnect event).

If you want to do some stuff and then close the socket, then you need to close the socket only from some event handler that indicates that your operation is complete and you are now done with the socket.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Without the socket.close() line the same result occurs. The connection merely hangs and no events are called. I've tried other event names and those also are not called.

Comment: @aaronfarr - You're going to need to do some debugging.  There's nothing else obviously wrong with the client-side code you show.  I'd suggest you install event handlers for the events `connect_error`, `connect_timeout` and `error` and see if any of those are triggered.  Also, `socket.on('connect', function(socket) {` should be `socket.on('connect', function() {` without the `socket` parameter.  For client-side code, you already have the `socket`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call socket.close() when you want to close the connection from the raspberry pi. Also, the socket.io-client documentation does not use the .connect method, but instead calls `require('socket.io-client')(serverUrl)`

```
var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io-client');
var serverUrl = 'http://remoteserver.com';

console.log('Connecting to ' + serverUrl);
var socket = io(serverUrl);

socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connection established!');
    console.log(socket.id);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Disconnected from server');
});

//Removed the socket.close() line
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Without the socket.close() line the same result occurs. Your example would say "Connecting to http://remoteserver.com" and just hang. It will never reach inside the "connect" event. I added the socket.close() line to see if I could at least trigger a disconnect event on the server side (it did not). So something else must be going on here.

Comment: Updated answer.